# How do you get the average of 20 random samples, all in one cell? for excel

Tags: excel, random, average

How do you get the average of 20 random samples, all in one cell? for excel
This is for the sake of space in excel, and also I because I need it to get 1000 of these samples.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem, you have 1000 samples and want a rolling average of each set of 20?

Regardless, I decided to tackle it for the sake of learning and came up with:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("R"&(((ROW()-1)*20)+1)&"C"&1,FALSE):INDIRECT("R"&(ROW()*20)&"C"&1,FALSE))
```

This assumes that the values are A1:A1000.  This would go in B1:B##.  I sincerely doubt I understand the problem, but it was fun anyway.